# How to get ordered list of labels after fitting sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
train_index, test_index = next(iter(ShuffleSplit(821, train_size=0.2, test_size=0.80, random_state=42)))
print train_index, len(train_index)
print test_index, len(test_index)

features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(features, labels, train_size=0.33, random_state=42)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
pred = clf.predict(features_test, labels_test)
print pred, len(pred)
```

A few questions from this code:

1. Why do I need the cross_validation.train_test_split line in order to fit and predict with my classifier? (I am not doing any preprocessing on my data except for stopword removal I have already done)
2. Do the test and train indexes correspond to the classified & predicted labels? My goal is to get **all** my labels, in their original order, after fitting and predicting them. My features and labels used for training and testing are from a pandas dataframe (two columns), and I need the predicted labels, in order, so that I can feed them back into the pandas dataframe.
3. Is there a way to predict the labels for the whole set, and not just the test set?

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

1. Because your decision tree classifier has to be *trained* before it can predict anything. It's not a magic algorithm. It has to be shown examples of what to do before it can work out what to do on other things.

   `cross_validation.test_train_split()` facilitates this by splitting your data into a test and training dataset in such a way that you can analyse how well it performed later on. Without this, you have no way of assessing how well your decision tree classifier actually performed.

   You can create your own testing and training data without `test_train_split()` (and I suspect that was what you were trying to do with `ShuffleSplit()`), but you *will* need at least some training data.
2. `test_index` and `train_index` have nothing to do with your data. Full stop. They come from a randomly generated process that is completely unrelated to what `test_train_split()` does.

   The purpose of `ShuffleSplit()` is to *give* you the indices to partition your data into training and test yourself. `test_train_split()` will instead choose their *own* indices and partition based on those indices. You should either use one or the other and *sensibly*.
3. Yes. You can always just call

   `pred = clf.predict(features)` or `pred = clf.predict(features_test + features_train)`

### The Full Story

- You need `cross_validation` if you want to do this right. The whole *purpose* of cross-validation is to avoid overfit.

  Basically, if you run your model on both the training and the testing data, then your model is going to perform really well on the training set (because, well, that's what you trained it on) and that's going to skew your overall metrics of how well your model will perform on real data.

  It's a lot like asking a student to perform in an exam and then in real life: if you want to know whether your student learned from the process of preparing for an exam, you don't give him another exam, you ask him to demonstrate his skills in the real world dealing with unknown and complex data.

  If you want to know if your model will be *useful*, then you want to cross-validate. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) puts it best:

  > In a prediction problem, a model is usually given a dataset of known
  >   data on which training is run (training dataset), and a dataset of
  >   unknown data (or first seen data) against which the model is tested
  >   (testing dataset).
  >
  > The goal of cross validation is to define a
  >   dataset to "test" the model in the training phase (i.e., the
  >   validation dataset), in order to limit problems like overfitting, give
  >   an insight on how the model will generalize to an independent dataset
  >   (i.e., an unknown dataset, for instance from a real problem), etc.

  `cross_validation.train_test_split` doesn't do anything *except* split the dataset into training and testing data for you.
- But perhaps you don't care about metrics, and that's fine. The question then becomes: is it *possible* to run a decision tree classifier without a training dataset?

  The answer is **no**. Decision tree classifiers are [supervised algorithms](https://zyxo.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/why-decision-trees-is-the-best-data-mining-algorithm/): they need to be trained on data before they can generalise their model to new results. If you don't give them any data to train on, it will be unable to do anything with any data you feed it in `predict`.
- Finally, while it is perfectly possible to get the labels for the whole set (see tl;dr) , it is a **really bad idea** if you actually care about whether or not you're getting sensible results.

  You *already* have the labels for the testing and training data. You don't *need* another column that includes prediction on the testing data, because they'll either come out to be identical or close enough to identical.

  I can't think of a single meaningful reason to get back predicted results for your training data short of trying to optimise how it's performing on your training data. If that's what you are trying to do, *then do that*. What you are doing right now is definitely not that, and I encourage you to think strongly about what your reasons are for blindly inserting numbers into your table without due cause to believe they actually mean something.

  There are ways to improve this: get back an accuracy metric, for example, or try to do *k*-fold cross-validation to model accuracy, or look at [log-loss or AUC or any one of number of metrics](http://blog.dato.com/how-to-evaluate-machine-learning-models-part-2a-classification-metrics) to gauge whether or not your model is performing well.

Answer (score 1):

Using both ShuffleSplit and train_test_split is redundant. You do not even appear to be using the indices returned by ShuffleSplit.

An example of how to use the indices return by ShuffleSplit is below. X and y are np.array. X is number of instances by number of features. y contains the labels of each row.

```
train_inds, test_inds = train_test_split(range(len(y)),test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
X_train, y_train = X[train_inds], y[train_inds]
X_test , y_test  = X[test_inds] , y[test_inds]
```

You should not test on your training data! But if you want to see what happens just do

```
pred = clf.predict(features_train)
```

Also you do not need to pass the labels to predict. You should be using

```
score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, pred)
```